# How to do partial update in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm use Solr 6.1.0

I need to quick to do partial update,

How to do it?

it does have any solr API or SolrNet can do that?

have any example?

Comment: this may help http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: it only can use command to do update?

Comment: can also use SolrJ refer this http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You can update a document this way :

```
var document = new MyItem() { Id = 5 , Title = "Bad Title", Content="Bad Content"};
var header = await _solrOperations.AtomicUpdateAsync(
    document, new []
    {
         new AtomicUpdateSpec("title",  AtomicUpdateType.Set, "Awesome title"),
         new AtomicUpdateSpec("content",  AtomicUpdateType.Set, "Awesome content")
    });
await _solrOperations.CommitAsync();
```

Comment: I update a non-existing document e.g. id=test-123 with AtomicUpdateType.Add and Solr create a new document has this id and one filed. Do you know how to prevent it create new in this case?